# Clicking command for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

im not really a programmer but i do understand coding a little. I have been using a simple command line running in google chrome's debugger console. What it does is that it continuously clicks a button from a website. Here's the code im using:

```
var i =0;
function f() {
$('#clickbtn').click()
i++;
if (i < 50000) {
setTimeout( f, 1100);
}
}
f();
```

The thing is,there's no way to pause or stop the script aside from closing the chrome tab. Anyone can give me a command to pause/stop the current running script? Thanks.